# How to bind multiple classes in web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
$.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    data: "{myEvents: " + JSON.stringify(myEvents) + ", myRecurrences: " + JSON.stringify(myRecurrences) + "}",
    url: "/signupadmin/api/SignupAdminAPI/SaveEvent",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (obj)
     {
          alert("success");
     },
     error: function (obj)
     {
          alert(obj.error());
     }


    });


  [HttpPost]
    public bool SaveEvent(EvancedEventData myEvents,RecurrenceData myRecurrences)
    {
        return true;
    }
```

I have used two class files(evancedeventdata and recurrencedata) as mentioned and trying to bind the json objects to two classes from ajax but it throws the error "cannot bind multiple parameters"  can you one suggest a reason why its not getting binded

Comment: can anyone suggest some answers for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be better to support questions like this with examples of the data, such as the JSON string you're posting and the Exception report.

However, try creating a wrapper class to encapsulate myEvents and myRecurrences, something like:

```
public class MyWrapperClass
{
  EvancedEventData myEvents {get;set;}
  RecurrenceData myRecurrences {get;set;}
}
```

Then change your POST action to expect the wrapper class:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SaveEvent(MyWrapperClass data)
{
    return true;
}
```

Then you should be able to read the data like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public bool SaveEvent(MyWrapperClass data)
{
    var events = data.myEvents
    //do stuff with the events

    var recurrences = data.myRecurrences
    //do stuff with the recurrences

    return true;
}
```

(above is just an example - you no need to create and use separate variables to access the data).

Hope this helps.

Ben

Comment: still i get the binding objects values as null(myEvents ,myRecurrences )

Comment: i have used the above mentioned,the web api method gets hit but the model valaue shows null.Can anyone suggest a solution

Comment: Yeah it works when i set the same name as the one in ajax post method. Thanks